# Learning about keras library, improving weights and bias

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am a new user trying to learn more about neural network. 
My question is. 
When keras is training. and is changing the accurasy (weights and bias improving), Is keras saving the last accuray with more percent?

for example. (the last NET that I did)

```
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 352us/sample - loss: 0.1273 - acc: 0.9605
Epoch 13573/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 380us/sample - loss: 0.1106 - acc: 0.9580
Epoch 13574/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 397us/sample - loss: 0.0660 - acc: 0.9764
Epoch 13575/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 0s 308us/sample - loss: 0.0849 - acc: 0.9707
Epoch 13576/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 359us/sample - loss: 0.0549 - acc: 0.9815
Epoch 13577/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 359us/sample - loss: 0.0502 - acc: 0.9828
Epoch 13578/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 331us/sample - loss: 0.0492 - acc: 0.9834
Epoch 13579/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 375us/sample - loss: 0.0531 - acc: 0.9841
Epoch 13580/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 0s 312us/sample - loss: 0.0445 - acc: 0.9866
Epoch 13581/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 375us/sample - loss: 0.0438 - acc: 0.9860
Epoch 13582/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 373us/sample - loss: 0.0601 - acc: 0.9796
Epoch 13583/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 406us/sample - loss: 0.0905 - acc: 0.9669
Epoch 13584/20000
1570/1570 [==============================] - 1s 420us/sample - loss: 0.1169 - acc: 0.9580
```

If I decide to end the current training. Keras take the weights and bias with the acc: 0.9866 or Keras will take the last? (in this case 0.9580) with more loss.

In case Keras take the last. I would like to know if there are any posibility for be able to add some lines and save weights and bias (when the acc(last) > acc(past)).

just in case. A simple code example.

```
X = # Data imput
Y = # Data output

model = keras.Sequential([ keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, 14)),
                           keras.layers.Dense(56, activation='relu'),
                           keras.layers.Dense(28, activation='relu'),
                           keras.layers.Dense(14, activation='relu'),
                           keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='relu'),
                           keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax') ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=20000)

test_loss,test_acc = model.evaluate(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I decide to end the current training. Keras take the weights and
>   bias with the acc: 0.9866 or Keras will take the last? (in this case
>   0.9580) with more loss.

Keras will take the last. To save the best weights, you can pass the `ModelCheckpoint` callback via the `callbacks` argument to `model.fit`. For writing custom logic to save the weights you can use `LambdaCallback`.

https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint

https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback